# Integrating $\sin(xy)$

Tags: integration

We are given the following:

$$\int \sin(xy)dy$$

We start by assigning anything algebraic into our first variable, $u$. Recalling LIATE (Logarithmic, Inverse-Trig., Algebra, Trig., Exponential) we start with algebra.

If I assign $$u=xy$$ then

$$\int \sin(u)\frac{du}{x}dy$$

Hence my confusion. Perhaps someone could help.

Comment: Where is the ratio $du/x$ coming from ?

Comment: Something went wrong, you have an extra $dy$ in your last integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are integrating with respect to $y$, so treat $x$ as a constant.

Your $u$-sub is done incorrectly: if $u=xy$, then applying $d/dy$ to both sides yeilds $(du)/(dy)=x$ or $du/x=dy$, which would yeild

$$\int sin(u)du/x=(\int sin(u)du)/x$$

since $x$ is a constant.

(also, putting dollar signs around your math makes it in the correct format)

For a solution not using $u$ substitution:

We know that $\frac{d}{dy}\cos(xy)= -x\sin(xy)$. If we modify the function we started with by dividing by $-x$, we will get the integrand of the problem you want to answer $\frac{d}{dy}(-\frac{\cos(xy)}{x})=\sin(xy)$.

Comment: I'll have another go at it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I know the integral of $\sinx$ is $-\cosx$, so how is it being divided?

Comment: Alright. I know I have it 100% now. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can take x as a constant to get $-\cos(xy)/x$.

Comment: Hmm. I cannot seem to muster it. If we treat $x$ as a constant its like $\sin(2y)$ which has the identity $2sinycosy$ Should I take that route?

Comment: In case of 2 you may go ahead with that but $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Of course. Could someone just show me? The latex is starting to frustrate me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is a constant, since $x$ is a constant, so you can take it out to get $$\frac{1}{x} \int \sin(u) du$$

which you should be able to integrate.

Comment: How is it $\frac{1}{x}$ I don't understand "take it out". It seems as though you are dividing arbirtrarily.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int \sin xy \ dy$$

As you've done: let $u = xy$, $\frac{du}{dy}=x $

$$\int \sin xy \ dy = \int \frac{\sin u}{x} du$$

$$  \frac{-\cos u}{x} + c =  \frac{-\cos xy}{x} + c$$

Hint: when integrating wrt y, x becomes a constant so you don't need to worry about it ($\sin xy $ is a function of two variables).